# How to Set Up a Single Page Application in phonegap within a single HTML page?

Tags: cordova

```
renderHomeView: function() {
    var html =
            "<div class='header'><h1>Home</h1></div>" +
            "<div class='search-view'>" +
            "<input class='search-key'/>" +
            "<ul class='employee-list'></ul>" +
            "</div>"
    $('body').html(html);
    $('.search-key').on('keyup', $.proxy(this.findByName, this));
},
```

Comment: Can't you use Angular or JQuery mobile?

Comment: please give some help in angular or jquery mobile ....

Answer (score 0):

Go to https://angularjs.org/

You can follow the tutorials in it to get you started.

Place the index.html file including your other project folders in the www folder. Now if you build for ios/android platforms, it should copy the files into respective folders and then you can run them on the device.

Comment: Can you mark answer as correct if you are happy? Thanks